# Render outcome of "action" attribute?

Tags: jsf, attributes, action, renderer

i want to completely rewrite a `<h:commandButton>` renderer. Now i'm stuck at rendering the "action" attribute of the button. Is there a possibility to render this attribute the same way it gets rendered by the standard renderer ? Is there a possibility to retrieve the generated script from somewhere ? Furthermore i don't want to use third party libs, if possible.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It doesn't end up in HTML output at all, so your question is very confusing. Have you for instance looked at source code of standard renderer?

Comment: sorry, i meant the rendered script which is tied to the ‘onclick’ event. Nope i haven't yet. I have the myfaces src, will it help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, BalusC was right. There is no generated Javascript.

But there was another thing i forgot about. One needs to add the following code: `button.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(button));` in the `decode` method of the according component renderer, where "button" is the UIComponent parameter of the "decode" method.

Thanks a lot BalusC !